# 80s-90s Scifi movie about miners in the arctic

Tags: story-identification

The best I can remember about this movie is that their drilling in a remote facility surrounded by snow, while drilling the machine gets jammed and they are forced to stop, after they raise the drill and stop for the night this blue alien starts killing them. after the main guy wounds the alien and its blue blood spills on his own wounds he realizes that it heals and regenerates his wound 100%, this part I am not sure but I think the aliens were the ones who had created the humans in the first place anyways this is an old movie I had seen as a child and never found again.

Comment: Not an exact fit, but might it be [*Deep Freeze* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_(film))?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Trilobites are related to crabs. I'd guess they have blue blood...

Comment: is the facility on earth?

Comment: Isn't there an X-Files episode like that?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for **[Nightworld: Survivor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187534/)** (1999)

[image: Movie Cover]

> An oil rig crew discovers an ancient evil far beneath the Earth's surface, which may be responsible for a series of murders.