# Movie about an alien discovered by a drilling team, and a goo that heals sick humans

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a movie from some time ago (15+ years).

A team is drilling, I think drilling in cold weather when the drill hits some goo.  One of the drillers was sick came in contact with the goo and a few hours later is healthy.  The scientist tests the goo and finds it's made to heal humans, at this time a drill team member is killed by the alien.  The drill team then believes the alien is there to farm humans for food.

It isn't *The Thing*, *Ice Crawlers*, or *Deep Freeze*.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Possibly a dupe of this question; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143227/80s-90s-scifi-movie-about-miners-in-the-arctic - The answer was *Nightworld (AKA Survivors)*

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [*Survivor*](https://www.filmaffinity.com/en/film527452.html) (AKA *Survivors* AKA *Nightworld: Survivor*, 1999).

> Virtually every "alien at large" movie ever filmed is referenced in
>   the made-for-TV shocker Survivor, which nonetheless manages to sustain
>   audience attention with a few adroit cliché reversals. It seems that,
>   billions of years ago, a race of extraterrestrials bred
>   pre-evolutionary human beings for organ-harvesting purposes.
>   Unfortunately, the alien ship bearing these primitive humans crashed
>   on contact with the earth, and has remained frozen in the Arctic
>   wastes ever since. Flash-forward to the present: Oil driller Adam King
>   (Greg Evigan) and his team, cut off from civilization, inadvertently
>   revive the sole survivor of the long-ago crash. Turns out that this
>   creature is very, very hungry after his long sleep--and he has a
>   distinct preference for the taste of human flesh!

You can watch the full movie below