# Arctic science fiction movie with a sleeping alien that farms people and has a blue gel that heals them

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

Great movie where aliens want to call home by way and say there is food here...

- Underground drilling.
- Blue gel that heals terrible wounds
- We're the cows.
- Maybe 70s or 80s movie.
- Saw it on TV.

Comment: This is a good start to a question, but it's a little unclear. It might help if you added more details about where you were when you saw the movie, what language it was in, and anything else you can remember visually or tonally about the movie. Even thoughts about the music could help. Right now, the question reads like a list, more than a description.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I think it was answered here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143227/80s-90s-scifi-movie-about-miners-in-the-arctic

Answer (score 3):

As [the guest](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201780/arctic-science-fiction-movie-with-a-sleeping-alien-that-farms-people-and-has-a-b#comment551651_201780) indicated, this is likely the same film as in [80s-90s Scifi movie about miners in the arctic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143227/80s-90s-scifi-movie-about-miners-in-the-arctic), where the answer was **[Nightworld: Survivor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187534/)** (1999)

[image: Movie Cover]

> An Alaskan oil rig crew in the middle of the Arctic Tundra hit something while drilling 10 miles beneath the Earth's surface. Instead of oil, a strange blue substance comes through the pipelines. Then when the drill is blown out mysteriously, the radar shows it was pushed out by a 7 foot tall object. One by one crew members are found gruesomely murdered and when they discover what they let loose, they end up fighting for more than their own lives.

[The](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw0632583/?ref_=tt_urv) [reviews](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw1773389/?ref_=tt_urv) have more information:

> This film is an Alien clone even down to the opening credits. Well actually, it's a clone and combo of several sci-fi classics. Is had the plot of "Alien," the setting of "The Thing," and a creature that's a cross between the Predator and the Queen Alien from "Aliens." However, it does have a pretty interesting premise. Turn out that human were bred billions of years ago at the dawn of evolution as harvest for a race of aliens. But the alien crashed and was frozen in the Arctic, and he was perserved until the humans revived him in present day. No kidding. And now he want to finish the job he started: eat us!

....

> 1,000,000,000 years ago extraterrestrial beings land on earth which is still devoid of life. One of the aliens is trapped by a volcano eruption and waits patiently until... human beings drill for oil and release it from its underground cave. Soon the usual story unfolds: some want to kill the beast, while others want to make money from the sensational creature, even at the risk of everyone's life. Although the elements of the movie are obviously taken from "Alien" (evil corporation), "Predator" (just look at the creature) and "The Thing" (isolated station in Antarctica), this is a better monster movie than some others. It has at least one good story idea: the monster carries a blue healing glue and sometimes doesn't seem hostile despite the kills. Well, it surely must know everything about longevity!

### Trailer

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.